# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method

Tags: android, build.gradle, rx-java2

I just start using RxJava in my projects, i have got this error : 
**java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method getService()Lcom/app/seddik/yomii/api/GalleryPhotosService;**

In this class the error has occured, and says :
 **No static method getService()Lcom/app/seddik/yomii/api/GalleryPhotosService; in class Lcom/app/seddik/yomii/api/GalleryPhotosService; or its super classes (declaration of 'com.app.seddik.yomii.api.GalleryPhotosService' appears in /data/app/com.app.seddik.yomii-2/base.apk:classes27.dex)
                                                       at com.app.seddik.yomii.data.datasource.GalleryPhotosDataSource.(GalleryPhotosDataSource.java:40)**

```
public class GalleryPhotosDataSource extends ItemKeyedDataSource<Integer, GalleryPhotosItems> {

private GalleryPhotosService galleryPhotosService;

private CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable;

private MutableLiveData<NetworkState> networkState = new MutableLiveData<>();

private MutableLiveData<NetworkState> initialLoad = new MutableLiveData<>();

/**
 * Keep Completable reference for the retry event
 */
private Completable retryCompletable;

GalleryPhotosDataSource(CompositeDisposable compositeDisposable) {
    this.galleryPhotosService = GalleryPhotosService.getService();
    this.compositeDisposable = compositeDisposable;
}
....
```

The error appear in this line :

```
        this.galleryPhotosService = GalleryPhotosService.getService();
```

My gradle dependencies :

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
 apply plugin: 'me.tatarka.retrolambda'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion "27.0.0"
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.app.seddik.yomii"
    minSdkVersion 15
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}

dependencies {
compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'

})

retrolambdaConfig 'net.orfjackal.retrolambda:retrolambda:2.5.1'
// Support libraries
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.0'
// Retrofit
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.4.0'

compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.0'
// Glide
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.6.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:4.6.1'
compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:okhttp3-integration:4.6.1'
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
// Others
compile 'com.github.chrisbanes:PhotoView:2.1.3'
compile 'com.github.varunest:sparkbutton:1.0.5'
compile 'com.makeramen:roundedimageview:2.2.1'
compile 'com.andkulikov:transitionseverywhere:1.7.8'
compile 'jp.co.cyberagent.android.gpuimage:gpuimage-library:1.3.0'
compile 'com.zhihu.android:matisse:0.4.3'
compile 'com.seatgeek:placesautocomplete:0.3-SNAPSHOT'
compile 'id.zelory:compressor:2.1.0'
compile 'org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.1.1'
compile 'com.github.florent37:shapeofview:1.1.2'
 // Firebase Messaging
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
compile 'cn.pedant.sweetalert:library:1.3'
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
 //Google services
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:15.0.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:15.0.0'

// find bugs
compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1'
// Timber for logging
compile 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:4.6.1'
//Architecture Components
compile "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.0"
//Paging
compile "android.arch.paging:runtime:1.0.1"
//Rx
compile 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.0'
compile  'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0'

testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

This my interface Retrofit Service :

```
public interface GalleryPhotosService {

 // Retrofit services
static GalleryPhotosService getService() {
    Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(AppConfig.URL_UPLOAD_PHOTOS)
            .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.create())
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build();
    return retrofit.create(GalleryPhotosService.class);
}}
```

Comment: my interface is already public, so its redundant to make method public ..

Comment: Very interesting error. Try to Invalidate caches/Restart... or maybe you have another GalleryPhotosService.java in you project

Comment: I tried but nothing..